# How to write this function in coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

I am struggling to re-produce a function like this in coffeescript could someone help me out a little.

```
// Listen to message from child window
 eventer(messageEvent,function(e) {
     console.log('parent received message!:  ',e.data);
 },false);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code translates to this equivalent one in CoffeeScript:

```
# Listen to message from child window
eventer messageEvent, ((e) ->
  console.log "parent received message!:  ", e.data
), false
```

You can always use this tool in the future if you need help with the CoffeeScript equivalence of a JavaScript code:

http://js2coffee.org/

Answer (score 0):

```
# Listen to message from child window
eventer messageEvent, (e) ->
     console.log "parent received message!:  #{e.data}"
, false
```

[Verified](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3a%23%20Listen%20to%20message%20from%20child%20window%0Aeventer%20messageEvent%2C%20%28e%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20console.log%20%22parent%20received%20message!%3A%20%20%23%7Be.data%7D%22%0A%2C%20false) with [coffeescript.org](http://coffeescript.org/)'s sandbox CoffeeScript compiler.